# Deploy Nativescript on the fly with JRebel for Android

Tags: android, nativescript, jrebel

I like Nativescript to build Android Apps but it takes too ling to livesync the changes to Android using the

```
tns livesync android --watch
```

Is there a way to use "JRebel for Android" to do the sync to the Phone while changing code in Nativescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's likely possible, there are other solutions.

This(nativescript-liveedit) is the best way to develop against Android with NativeScript currently: https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-liveedit @NathanaelA's plugin is brilliant and it's extremely fast at syncing changes.

Also, the NativeScript team is currently working on what they're calling 'LiveEdit' also which will be syncing the changes to source code in ~1second according to their issue on the repo, it's behind a flag on the CLI with NS 2.3 I believe and it might only be on iOS right now with Android in the works.